# Can I filter questions I've upvoted by tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, voting

Within my profile, I can see the questions I've voted on. They consist of questions related to [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) , [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) etc.. How can I filter these questions by specific tags? For e.g.: I want to refer some question I voted on - I remember the language and the topic. But instead of searching through the 100s or 1000s , it would be easier to have a tag based filter.

[image]