# Filter vote casts based on a specific post type

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

If we open our user activity tab and go to the `votes` tab, we can filter our vote casts by

- `All`
- `Upvote`
- `Downvote`
- `Deletion`
- etc

Why isn't there an option to filter the votes casts on a specific type of post?

For example, I want to view all my votes on questions. Because AFAIK the vote casts are sorted based on date and there is no option to sort it by the type of post that I voted on.

*Why would I need such feature?*

I think that it will help me to search or find and go back to a specific post since they are mixing up both questions and answers which makes it hard to dig through the posts.

*Why would I search for posts that I voted on?*

So I can go back to those posts in case I forgot something from the post or I suddenly find myself in need of the post.

*Why not use bookmarks?*

Bookmarks are used for posts that I think/expect to be useful in the future, but now what if I want to go back to a post that I never expected to be useful? Like sometimes suddenly needed to solve a problem and I remembered that I ever ran across a post with that kind of problem, but unfortunately I already forgot something from the post

Of course I will not be able to find them through my bookmarks because at the time I saw the post, I did not expect that I will use it someday. And bookmarking every single post that I found just in case is obviously not a great idea which is why I think this feature will be helpful.

Comment: Why would that be useful? Aka: what is your use case that would warrant such filter?

Comment: i think that filter could be pretty useful if i only wanted to search for answers/questions so i don't have to dig through all my vote histories since the vote histories there are mixing up both questions and answers. Lets say a user has voted mostly on questions, it will be hard to search for answer post from the vote histories right?

Comment: But why would you search for something you voted on? You either care about your votes so you revisit them from time to time or you don't care about them. What would a search here give you for benefit that you can't do with a normal search?

Comment: hmm i sometimes search from my votes because i forgot something from the post so i had go back and see it, or maybe so i can go back to the post for some reason. An alternative is i can probably like bookmark it or something but then it will be hard if i bookmarked too much

Comment: For bookmarks goes that those are stored in SEDE and are not anonymized to searching in SEDE can work for those. I'm still not convinced this is a feature many users would benefit from.

Comment: somewhat related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336718/can-i-filter-questions-ive-upvoted-by-tags

Comment: Yeah it probably will not help a ton amount of users but i'm pretty sure it could be useful somehow cuz i've seen some people going back to a post after a certain time for whatever reason

Comment: If you want to be able to find a question or answer in the future bookmark it (I mean the feature on [so], not the browser feature). If you want to get notifications about it, follow it. There's no need for this feature when another feature provides the solution.

Comment: i find a lot of posts useful here on SO, and i dont know if i will have to go back to the post in the future so if i will just bookmark a ton of posts just in case, isnt it the same case? it will still be hard to dig through all the mixed up posts, or am i missing something?

Comment: So you think that you'll be able to find the post more efficiently in your upvotes? I upvote *far* more posts than I bookmark, so I would be surprised if I find it easier to find a particular question/answer in my upvotes that I would in my bookmarks. I doubt you bookmark *every* question/answer you upvote; if you are, then you're not making your life easier here. Just bookmark the one's you think are going to be helpful to you again the future.

Comment: Im not saying that i will find posts easily with vote casts, what im saying is if i bookmark the posts that i think will be useful, what if i want to go back to a post that i never expected to be useful? like sometimes i suddenly needed to do something and i remembered that i ever ran accros a post with that kind of problem but i *forgot* somthing from the post or anything like that, of course i did not expect that i will use it someday and that i would forget the answer from the post when i saw the it so i will not bookmark it right? Cuz bookmarking every single post that i vote is not good

Comment: Can you be more clear in your question on the definition of "type"? E.g., is it only the binary "question" / "answer"? (***Without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: yes it is only the binary "question/answer"

Comment: Would you say you vote more than twice as often as you bookmark? if so, this feature would be less useful than bookmarks.

Comment: Going back and looking at things you previously voted on doesn't seem like something votes are made for or should be used for, and using them for that might encourage you to vote much more rarely than you ideally should. I've honestly forgotten that the votes tab even exists and I'm not really in favour of extending that (or really even keeping it).

Comment: @BernhardBarker yeah i kinda agree but i still dont get why are they even made, perhaps there are alternative ways/features to do this?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy agreed, bookmarks are way more useful since it only stores the posts that are likely useful in the future, but doesnt mean that this feature isnt useful since it has a similar but different use